# Arduino Serial object data type, to create a variable holding a reference to a port

Tags: types, embedded, serial-port, arduino

I'm working on a project with an ArduinoMega2560. There are multiple serial ports available, and I'd like to have a variable to hold a reference to one of them, something like this:

```
SerialPort port;
if (something == somethingElse)
    port = Serial;
else
    port = Serial1;

byte b = 5;
port.write(b);
```

However, the Arduino documentation is either limited or I haven't found the information I'm looking for. I think what I need it "What is the type for Serial, Serial1, etc?".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The underlying C++ type for the Serial objects is `HardwareSerial`. You can find that in the files in `<arduino path>\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino`. You can then use a pointers using code like this:

```
HardwareSerial *port;
if (something == somethingElse)
    port = &Serial;
else
    port = &Serial1;

byte b = 5;
port->write(b);
```

Comment: Can it be done with references? So that method calls are with . not ->

Comment: @Osman-pasha: Probably but it would be more awkward to define the reference. At a guess it could be something like `HardwareSerial& port = (something == somethingElse) ? Serial : Serial1; byte b = 5; port.write(b);`

Comment: @tinman: oh I missed that restriction of references, thank you

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the Leonardo which complains about `Serial_*` not being converted to `HardwareSerial*`.

Comment: It seems to work better if we use the `Stream *` type. But then boolean operations fail like `if(!(*port))` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Arduino, but the way this is commonly done on most microcontrollers is that you point straight at the register area of the periheral, in this case the serial port. Lets assume your MCU maps those registers like this:

```
// serial port 1
0x1234 SERIAL_CONTROL_REG
0x1235 SERIAL_DATA_REG
0x1236 SERIAL_STATUS_REG

// serial port 2
0x2000 SERIAL_CONTROL_REG
0x2001 SERIAL_DATA_REG
0x2002 SERIAL_STATUS_REG
```

You can then keep track of a the port with a pointer, like this:

```
#define SERIAL_PORT1 ((volatile uint8_t*)0x1234)
#define SERIAL_PORT2 ((volatile uint8_t*)0x2000)

typedef volatile uint8_t* serial_port_t;
...

serial_port_t port;

if (something == somethingElse)
    port = SERIAL_PORT1;
else
    port = SERIAL_PORT2;
```

This can then be expanded further so that you can use the registers just as variables, for example with macros:

```
#define SERIAL_CONTROL_REG(offset) (*(offset + 0))
#define SERIAL_DATA_REG(offset)    (*(offset + 1))
#define SERIAL_STATUS_REG(offset)  (*(offset + 2))

if(SERIAL_STATUS_REG(port) & some_mask)
{
  SERIAL_DATA_REG(port) = 0xAA;
}
```

This is how you typically write generic hardware drivers for MCU peripherals with more than one identical port on-board.

Comment: In the "Arduino Language", which I believe is just a preprocessor before handing off to g++, Serial is a pointer to an object, not a register. Their language makes quick prototyping pretty easy, but like I said above, the documentation leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: @Steve Oh? Then I would strongly recommend people to learn embedded programming instead of Arduino programming.

Comment: That would be true in many cases, but when timing isn't an issue, and development time needs to be kept to a minimum, doing `Serial.begin(9600); Serial.print("Simple text command");` is much easier and quicker than having to set up registers and interrupts. It's basically a pre-made, ready to go library someone else wrote.