# how to define a struct using macro

Tags: c, struct, macros

recently I've being working on stm32, dealing with some msg issues. I am trying to construct a queue to store messages from usart and can, then it comes to me that I should build a generic type for them. I tried to use a macro to define different kind of queues but errors yield.

here are my codes, I am expecting to use "USART_QUEUE2" as a type:

```
#define DEF_QUEUE(ITEM_TYPE,NAME) \
typedef struct #NAME \
{\
    (ITEM_TYPE)* buffer;    \
    void (*Push)((ITEM_TYPE)* src, struct #NAME * queue);\
}#NAME;\

DEF_QUEUE(u8,USART_QUEUE2)
```

the errors here are  `"message": "expected either a definition or a tag name" "message": "expected identifier or '(' before string constant"`

I don't know what to do to fix it. may someone help me out with this?

I tried ask ChatGPT, but clearly it can't deal with macro problems properly lol.
I've rolled in related questions, didn't find a precise solution.

Comment: From the first glance: `(ITEM_TYPE)` -> `ITEM_TYPE`, `#NAME` -> `NAME`.

Comment: `#NAME` will transform `NAME` to a string. Simply use `NAME`

Comment: Two problems: The first is your use of the *stringification* operator. When you use `#NAME` the preprocessor will create a literal string containing the value of `NAME`. So `DEF_QUEUE(u8,USART_QUEUE2)` will define a structure like `struct "USART_QUEUE2" { ... }`. The second problem is the trailing line-continuation character. The macros should not end with one.

Comment: You usually don't have the trailing ';' in the macro so you can include it on use.

Comment: Also, when having problems with the preprocessor and macros, I recommend you ask the compiler to stop after preprocessing, so you can see exactly what macros expand to.

Comment: appreciate all of the helps!!! by the way @Someprogrammerdude could you explain this further " I recommend you ask the compiler to stop after preprocessing, so you can see exactly what macros expand to", i never focus on this.

Comment: thanks a lot @AllanWind, your solution/modification works!!

Comment: If you use GCC, add the `-E` option and you will get the preprocessed source. As in `gcc -E input.c > input_preprocessed.c`

Comment: thanks. sounds interesting. i am using keil though, but i will try it.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific problem, this here is _not_ a good way to implement generic drivers for UART etc. Separate names for UART1, UART2 etc do you no good. Instead you should consider passing the base address of the hardware peripheral registers as a parameter to the UART driver. That is: `void uart_tx (volatile* uint32_t base, uint8_t data) { UARTTX(base) = data; ...` Where `UART_TX` is a macro for a hardware register of the form `#define UART_TX(base) ( *((base) + 123) )`, where 123 is the register offset counting from the first one in the UART part of the register map.

Comment: In order to create specific ring buffers etc per hardware UART, consider opaque types as shown at [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Comment: Here's a more concrete example of the register offset trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866648/584518

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! @Lundin ! perhaps i didn't fully understand your idea. i am just constructing a queue to manage the messages. for receiving and transmitting messages, i indeed use quite the same way as your suggestion like "USART->DR = data;", and there are standard functions to do this. i will check out your links though. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't use the usual `()` around macro values so this is extra brittle.
2. Don't use '#' here as that will create strings but you need identifiers.
3. (Not fixed) I don't like the style of having the '*' next to the type instead of the variable as it doesn't generalize (`int* a, b` is not `int *a, *b`).

```
#define DEF_QUEUE(ITEM_TYPE,NAME) \
typedef struct NAME \
{ \
    ITEM_TYPE* buffer; \
    void (*Push)(ITEM_TYPE* src, struct NAME* queue); \
} NAME

DEF_QUEUE(u8,USART_QUEUE2);
```

and here is the corresponding output:

```
typedef struct USART_QUEUE2 { u8* buffer; void (*Push)(u8 *src, struct USART_QUEUE2 *queue); } USART_QUEUE2;
```